# color row based on cell value in rhandsontable

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I am struggling to color full row of rhandsontable in my shiny app based on a cell value.

In the following example, I would like to format full row instead of one cell.

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

col_highlight = 2
row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(DF, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
               function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
               Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

               if(value == 'F' | value == 'f') {
               td.style.background = 'pink';
               } else if(value == 'J' | value == 'j') {
               td.style.background = 'lightgreen';
               } else if(value == 'X' | value == 'x') {
               td.style.background = 'lightblue'}

               }")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of renderer is that applied to all cells separately, so at the same time cell value can't be a 'F' and 'f'. For every row you have to select column 2 to check if value is 'F' and select column 3 to check if value is 'f'.

```
rhandsontable(DF, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
hot_cols(renderer = "
           function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

           if(instance.getData()[row][2] == 'F' | instance.getData()[row][3] == 'f'){
                td.style.background = 'pink';
           } else if(instance.getData()[row][2] == 'J' | instance.getData()[row][3] == 'j') {
                td.style.background = 'lightgreen';
           } else if(instance.getData()[row][2] == 'X' | instance.getData()[row][3] == 'x') {
                td.style.background = 'lightblue'
           }
        }")
```

Comment: Works perfectly... Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, just copying and pasting the same code above. using rhandsontable v0.3.6

Comment: @KiprasKančys, can you please enlighten me on how to check for string length in a cell or cells in a column and update background color if it exceeds a value?

Comment: Try this: `rhandsontable(data.frame(a = c('a' , 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd'))) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
           function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

           if(instance.getData()[row][0].length > 2) {
             td.style.background = 'pink'
           }
        }")`