# R Rhansontable - Color Specific Cells Conditionally On Other Table

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

This is my first post on SO, so please bear with me if my post is not fully aligned with the rules. Though I will do my best to give a clear description of my problem, the resources I already checked and provide a reproducible example.

First of all, let me explain the problem: I would like to highlight **specific cells** of a Rhandsontable filled with numeric values in Shiny using different colors (red and green) **according to a condition from another table** (same nb of columns/rows filled with boolean values, where TRUE=green, FALSE=red).

Let's say I want to start from the following two tables:

```
DF = data.frame(val = 1:3, big = LETTERS[1:3])

DF_condition = data.frame(val = c(TRUE, FALSE,FALSE), big = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
```

I would like the cells at `(1,1)` and `(2,2)`, i.e where the other table is set at TRUE to be green and all other cells to be red.

I have looked at multiple other posts within SO (and other) like these:

- [color row based on cell value in rhandsontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602317/color-row-based-on-cell-value-in-rhandsontable)
- [Color a whole row in rhandsontable based on a string value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142090/color-a-whole-row-in-rhandsontable-based-on-a-string-value-in-one-column)
- [Shiny and rhandsontable - Conditional cell/column formatting based on column sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746194/shiny-and-rhandsontable-conditional-cell-column-formatting-based-on-column-sum)

However, none of them solve my problem. Indeed, I am facing the three following main issues:

1. I am NOT trying to highlight an entire row / column but only specific cells
2. The conditional formatting should be done using a condition from another table
3. My database has hundred thousands of rows and around 20 columns (and I would like if possible to use a vectorized approach and not a loop through columns/rows)

As I am not familiar with JScript, used within rhandsontable, I am a bit stuck.

Please find below a minimal reproduceable example:

```
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    DF = data.frame(val = 1:3, big = LETTERS[1:3])
    DF_condition = data.frame(val = c(TRUE, FALSE,FALSE), big = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
    col_highlight = c(1,2)
    row_highlight = c(1,3)

    rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight-1, row_highlight = row_highlight-1) %>%
      hot_cols(renderer = "
               function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
               Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
               if (instance.params) {
               hcols = instance.params.col_highlight
               hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols]
               hrows = instance.params.row_highlight
               hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]
               }
               if (instance.params && hcols.includes(col) && hrows.includes(row)) td.style.background = 'red';
               }")
    })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which highlights the two first columns and the two first rows, whereas I would need only cells `(1,1)` and `(2,2)`.

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Updating question to see if anyone who can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking whether the column is in the Array `[1,2]` and whether the row is in the Array `[1, 2]`. All four combinations `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,1)` and `(2,2)` satisfy this requirement, which is why all those cells are colored red. Instead, you want to make sure that if the column is the first element of the Array `[1,2]`, then the row should also be the first element of the Array `[1,2]`, and not the second.
I'm no JavaScript expert, but something like this might work:

```
if (instance.params && hcols.includes(col) && hrows.includes(row) && (hcols.indexOf(col) == hrows.indexOf(row))) {
td.style.background = 'red';
}
```